# Android Studio error "This class should provide a default constructor"

Tags: android, compilation

I'm stuck. When I run my project on the debugger it is fine, and build returns no errors, but trying to generate an APK I get the error described in the title. I've tried many fixes suggested in various forums to no avail. I'm aware that I'm trying to extend a class that has no default constructor, but is that a serious problem? Should I disable this warning message somehow? Offending code:

```
public class WordListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CandidateWord> {
    public WordListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<CandidateWord> candidateWordList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, candidateWordList);
        ...
}
```

If I try to add an empty constructor, Studio highlights numerous errors, the crux of which is that there is no default constructor in parent class android.widget.ArrayAdapter.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Try to use public WordListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<CandidateWord> candidateWordList)

Comment: Please note: you should use List<T> instead of ArrayList<T> as parameter in the constructor definition.

Comment: @DrMartens ArrayList implements List so why would this cause a problem ? Don't get me wrong, you're right, coding against interfaces instead of concrete classes is better, but I'm unclear on why this would be the root of the issue.

Comment: How do you instantiate WordListAdapter?